# PCI addresses of 2 network ports differ only in "device function" field => they belong to the same NIC?

Tags: ethernet, nic, architecture, pci, lspci

I have multiple 10G ethernet ports on my server. Here is lspci for some of them:

```
81:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
81:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
83:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
83:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
85:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
85:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Let's take e.g. `81:00.0` and `81:00.1`. Their bus-id and device-id match.

Does this mean, they are the ports of the same NIC, i.e. share the same ethernet controller?

Answer (score 1):

82599ES [datasheet](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7kfbanrXSAhUBRhQKHYLUCGMQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intel.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fwww%2Fpublic%2Fus%2Fen%2Fdocuments%2Fdatasheets%2F82599-10-gbe-controller-datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGvvbFcWNHKb2qjpTNK2mg4VE2unA)(p. 64) states:

> PCIe device numbers identify logical devices within the physical device (the 82599 is a physical device). The 82599 implements a single logical device with two separate PCI
>   Functions: LAN 0 and LAN 1. The device number is captured from each type 0
>   configuration write transaction.

So at least in this case, `81:00.0` and `81:00.1` are 2 ports of the same NIC.